# How to batch-rename long file names into short ones under Linux?

Tags: linux, rename

I have a lot of data with file name (just for example):

```
dt_upd_global_merged_madt_uv_20100801_20100801_20110721.bil
dt_upd_global_merged_madt_uv_20100802_20100802_20110721.bil
dt_upd_global_merged_madt_uv_20100803_20100803_20110721.bil
```

What should I do if I want to rename that files into the following?

```
20100801.bil
20100802.bil
20100803.bil
```

Comment: http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/1/prename/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for f in *.bil; do

    n=$(echo "${f}"|sed -r 's/^.+([0-9]{8})_\1_[0-9]{8}[.]bil$/\1/'|grep -Ev '.bil$')
   #or:
   #n=`echo "${f}"|sed -r 's/^.+([0-9]{8})_\1_[0-9]{8}[.]bil$/\1/'|grep -Ev '.bil$'`

    if [ -n "${n}" ]; then
        mv "${f}" "${n}.bil"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way with Zsh (by calling `zsh` first, obviously):

```
autoload -U zmv
zmv 'dt_upd_global_merged_madt_uv_(*)_(*)_(*).bil' '$1.bil'
```

Or with the Perl `rename`:

```
rename 's/dt_upd_global_merged_madt_uv_(.*)_(.*)_(.*).bil/$1.bil/' *.bil
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk, -F option to specify `_` as the delimiter. The 7th field output plus ".bil" (for example) places `20100801.bil` in the `fnew` variable. 
Then mv the original name to the new name.

```
    for f in *.bil
    do
        fnew=$(awk -F_ '{print $7 ".bil"}' <<< $f);
        mv $f $fnew
    done
```